# Is there a Bazaar equivalent to `git commit --amend`?

Tags: bazaar

I'm playing around with Launchpad projects using Bazaar and getting along fairly well. However, coming from a Git background I'm really missing the ability to roll changes into the last commit---this happens frequently when I discover a small, stupid typo that *really* doesn't deserve its own commit or entry in a `debian/changelog` file.

Does Bazaar provide a command that serves the same purpose as `git commit --amend`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`bzr uncommit` + `bzr commit` but it does not populate your editor with old commit message. If you can use bzr-gtk or QBzr then use `bzr uncommit` + `bzr gcommit` (or `bzr qcommit`). The GUI commit dialogs are able to populate commit editor with old commit message.